# Save SQL data FROM an ARRAY such as print_r()

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following question
How do I save data from an array within the same file after registrations, here is the scenario.

user register on a site, he get as usual an ID as primary key for the SQL, for also a random code, in this case a random number, this number will later be use, but for now I only need a away to save my data...

so, when user register for the very first time, the script will generate 3 random questions from the sql which the table has over 400 question anyway, each user gets only 3 questions. so

here is my code to get this random questions...

```
 $questionsID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3");
        $ids = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($questionsID)){
            $ids[] = $row['id'];
                    }
print_r($ids);
```

with that I get only the ID's and thats all I need for now...

the end result is 3 ID's as I have stated in the SQL query that I only want 3 random ID's from the whole table, so it looks like this:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 3
)
```

but, I don't see that, only if I go to my browser, please bear with me I'm still learning
so, at this point I have my special code of 6 digits which is store in a different table

this code will be associated with the questions as the code is also associated to the user...
my tables are:
User, Special_code, questions, question_for_user

at the end my table questions_for_users should look like this

```
ID | special_code | question_id
1  | 444444       | 2
2  | 444444       | 1
3  | 444444       | 3
4  | 232323       | 56
5  | 232323       | 4
```

... and son on for each user per special code...

So my question is, how do I save my data into the sql table questions_for_user from the array, if the array is in the print_r($ids) ...
or if there is another way to save the data please share... Thank you.

---

So, I thank you all for helping me, some of your ideas did worked as standalone...
using jeroen solution did worked but as I put it in to my full code it stop working... 
I have never used serialize(), so I really don't know how that work, but I can guess something like this:
to be use to save data in my sql

```
$array_string=mysql_escape_string(serialize($array));
```

and something like

```
$array= unserialize($results['ids']);
```

to get the information... I don't know, I may be wrong.... anyways...

so I apology for what you are about to see:
I know this is not the best way to do it, and some developers will want to hit me in the head!...

in order for my to save the data I made another query inside my previews query as follow:

```
$questionsID = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3");
//        $ids = array();
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($questionsID)){
        $ids = $row['id'];
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO user_questions(special_code, question_id) VALUES ('$specialCode_by_POST','$ids')") or  die("".mysql_error());
}
```

This did the trick... :)
I got the table just the way I wanted

If you think that I should do this in a different way please share a solution, Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered json or serialization?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? As I read it you just need to insert 3 rows in your `questions_for_users` table, all with the same `special_code` and each with its own `question_id`.

Comment: Also, you can just use PHP's implode() function and create a string out of your array, which can look like "11|22|33", and then you can use PHP's explode() function to make an array out of it again. That way, you can just store regular strings in your database

Comment: @Daedalus, I have try json, I'll do so, thank you.

Comment: @jeroen , the problem I have is that how do I store the data from the array...

Comment: @FilipposKarapetis Karapetis, that is what I was thinking right know, I'll try and see if it works... Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems that the problem is populating the `questions_for_users` table.

You can build a simple insert statement that will insert all entries from your array at once.

Using PDO:

```
$values = array(':special_code' => $special_code);
$recs = array();
$sql = 'INSERT INTO questions_for_users (ID, special_code, question_id) VALUES ';
foreach ($ids as $id)
{
    $recs[] = "(NULL, :special_code, :question_id_{$id})";
    $values[":question_id_{$id}"] = $id;
}
$sql .= implode(',', $recs);

// prepare statement
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

// execute statement
$stmt->execute($values);
```

Comment: Thank you, I did a very basic code just to tryout the examples provided here, and your code did worked, but when I put it together with the rest of my code, it didn't work, the error I was getting was : Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object... I may be missing something, but overall it did worked thank you.... however I did a very nasty solution to my question...

Comment: @Tanker Note that I am using PDO and not the `mysql_*` functions. If you want to use this code, you need to connect using PDO (`$db` is my PDO connection in the example here).

Comment: Thank you, I should pay more attention, that's what I was missing, I wanted to give you a +1 but this thing is asking for 15 on reputation I only have 11 :( ... I don't log here to often, and I'm kind of new to this site... but you get the idea.. Thank you, your answer was useful to me.

Answer (score 0):

you could use `where IN id(2,1,3)` for question table or join tables

```
    $query = "SELECT questions.id, Special_code.code FROM questions, Special_code  
WHERE questions.id = Special_code.id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3";
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: for some reason every time I log in, I get different questions, the idea is to when you register for the first time to get your 3 random questions and that's it, you can log in as many time as you want but your questions wont change, so to my question is, now that I have my array in print_r($ids) how do I save that data in to another table... I mean, I know how to INSERT INTO table.... blah blah... what I don't know is how to strip the array so I can send the data to it's correct colum... Thank you.